# Excel 2010 Access to path is denied temp

Tags: c#, excel, permissions

I am using excel data reader to read data from an excel file.

> FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
>   **//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)**
>   IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
>   **//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)**
>   IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

This reads excel 1997-2003 format and excel 2007 format on my local machine and when we move it to our test server.

However, when moved to production, it works for excel 97-2003 files, but when I try to read 2007 files I receive the following error:

Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PORTALS03\ASPNET\LOCALS~1\Temp\TMP_Z129388041687919815' is denied.

How is it possible that the 97-2003 excel file can be read but the 2007 files throw access is denied?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess here that you probably aren't closing or disposing of the excel data reader.

OR you aren't properly disposing of the code that is creating that temp file to begin with.

Without seeing the code you are using to generate and read the file it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the Excel Data Reader creates Temp Files of the Excel files it reads. 
The Error sounds like there is no permission given to the directory where these Temp files are stored. 
So Excel Reader can't do its work.